# Vue search array for unique "Years": string, and make a new array with each element being a unique Year object key

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, sorting, vuejs3

I'm currently attempting to create a new array of objects sorted by year. What would be the best way to loop through an array of objects that look like this:

```
[
     {id: 42, count: 250, month: "January", year: 2024}
     {id: 37, count: 2023, month: "January", year: 2023}
     {id: 1, count: 1111, month: "January", year: 2022}
     {id: 2, count: 100, month: "February", year: 2022}
     {id: 3, count: 500, month: "March", year: 2022}
     {id: 6, count: 1, month: "April", year: 2022}
     {id: 8, count: 500, month: "May", year: 2022}

];
```

And create a new array that would look like this:

```
[
     {
       2024: [{id: 42, count: 250, month: "January", year: 2024}]
     },
     {
       2023: [{id: 37, count: 2023, month: "January", year: 2023}]
     },
     {
       2022: [
              {id: 1, count: 1111, month: "January", year: 2022},
              {id: 2, count: 100, month: "February", year: 2022},
              {id: 3, count: 500, month: "March", year: 2022},
              {id: 6, count: 1, month: "April", year: 2022},
              {id: 8, count: 500, month: "May", year: 2022}
           ]
      },
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way with forEach and find:

```js
const arr = [
     {id: 42, count: 250, month: "January", year: 2024},
     {id: 37, count: 2023, month: "January", year: 2023},
     {id: 1, count: 1111, month: "January", year: 2022},
     {id: 2, count: 100, month: "February", year: 2022},
     {id: 3, count: 500, month: "March", year: 2022},
     {id: 6, count: 1, month: "April", year: 2022},
     {id: 8, count: 500, month: "May", year: 2022}
]
const res = []
arr.forEach(a => {
  let ex = res.find(r => a.year in r)
  if(ex) {
    ex[a.year].push(a)
  } else res.push({[a.year]: [a]})
})
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let a = [
     {id: 42, count: 250, month: "January", year: 2024},
     {id: 37, count: 2023, month: "January", year: 2023},
     {id: 1, count: 1111, month: "January", year: 2022},
     {id: 2, count: 100, month: "February", year: 2022},
     {id: 3, count: 500, month: "March", year: 2022},
     {id: 6, count: 1, month: "April", year: 2022},
     {id: 8, count: 500, month: "May", year: 2022}

];
let c = []
a.forEach(e => {
    const obj = {}
    if(!c.some(item => item[e.year])){
        obj[e.year] = a.filter(item => item.year == e.year)
        c.push(obj)
    }
})
console.log(c)
```